# ECONNRESET Error response getting from flask python

Tags: python, api, flask, jsonify

I'm not getting the proper response for this particular API. Also , In actual implementation, I'm getting the proper 200 jsonify response when all things are running fine but if their is any exception and If I want to send back the response with 500 status code : the postman say Could not get response : "Error: read ECONNRESET" and in my console it display as "127.0.0.1 - - [04/Aug/2020 23:57:22] "←[37mPOST /hi HTTP/1.1←[0m" 500 -"

can someone please tell me , where I'm going wrong ?

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, abort, json
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import traceback

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@app.route("/hi", methods=['POST'])
def hi():
    val = 500
    dict_json = {"messgae": "lets work it out {} ".format(val)}
    return jsonify(dict_json), val
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today and found that it seems to be an issue with the flask server. It works fine usually however sometimes requests with postman would time out with the error you've mentioned.

Can you try hosting it instead with waitress?

To do that add this to the top of your file

**from waitress import serve**

then instead of running **app.run()** you run **serve(app, host='localhost', port=7777)**

oh, and for waitress to work you will of course need to run **pip install waitress** first!